# why does a statement i made in elif affect my previous if statement

Tags: python, if-statement, variables

```py
chosen_word=["pab"]
    
    #going through the letter
    for n in range (0,len(chosen_word)):
        if chosen_worda[n]==guess:#right letter
            word_is[n]=guess
    if word_is1==word_is:#if wrong letter #why is the word_is1=word_is implemented again
        life+=1
        print (f"wrong guess, you died {life}")
    elif word_is1!=word_is:#if right word 
        print (f"new word is{word_is}")
        word_is1=word_is
    
if word_is==chosen_worda:
    print ("you won pic")
elif life==3:
    print ("you lost pic")
```

This is the hangman game and even though I was expecting my statement in `elif word_is1=word_is` to be implemented only if the letter is correct and its not supposed to be true if its wrong it keeps it even in the next iteration, to see what I mean try with examples...first "q" then "a" then "b" it will say you lost

Comment: Please fix your code's formatting.

Comment: I think you need to edit your question to add in some additional code. There is not enough here to go on and most of what is here references stuff that we cannot see such as `chosen_worda`, `guess` or even the initial vales for `word_is` and `word_is1`